# TypeScript compilation error when selecting a property which is not a part of returned interface type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some code using external library which retrieves data with rest from a server. It looks like this:

```js
let value: ITypeValue & ITypeData = service.data.select('Name', 'Id', 'ChildId').get();

// ChildId is not a part of interface, but can be retrieved
forEach.value(item => (
  console.log(item.Id + ' - ' + item.Name + ' - ' + item['ChildId']);
));
```

Basically this code works, but if I take into account typescript, I get an error saying that `item['ChildId'] is not in type ItypeValue or ITypeData`, basicause this property is not part of that interface, BUT when I retrieve it it can be and it works fine, but due to typescript I get an error on compilation.

Any idea how to resolve that?

Basically I need someway to access this property... If I check during the debug mode, I see that it is there, but because it is not of type specified, typescript shows me an error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your remote resource returns the property your looking for, TypeScript  may still lack a way to affirm the property is present during compilation.

You can create a new interface.

```js
interface GetChildResponse extends ITypeValue, ITypeData {
  ChildId: string
}

let value: GetChildResponse = service.data.select('Name', 'Id', 'ChildId').get();
```

You can add an additional union with a third inline type definition.

```js
let value:ITypeValue & ITypeData & { ChildId: string }= service.data.select('Name', 'Id', 'ChildId').get();
    // ChildId is not a part of interface, but can be retrieved
    forEacht.value(item => ( 
    console.log(item.Id + ' - ' + item.Name + ' - ' + item['ChildId']);
));
```

I wouldn't recommend this, but you could extend the `ITypeData` interface too.

```js
interface ITypeData {
  ChildId string;
}
```

To be frank, I think your question stems from not knowing TypeScript fundamentals. I would checkout the [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) and playing around with an online TypeScript playground like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/

To learn more about interfaces, refer to [TypeScript Handbook: Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

To learn more about type unions, refer to [TypeScript Handbook: Unions and Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html).

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. If you don't mind me asking some other question in regards of that, what if I do a select of a complex object as child .select('Id', 'Name', 'Child').get(), but instead of getting whole child object, I need just and ID of the child, how could I specify that something like that .select('Id', 'Name', 'Child.Id or Child/Id')? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To get a better answer than I can immediately provide, look up the documentation for whatever external library you are using to access your remote resource. I'm not sure what you're using.

Comment: If you think I've answered your question, please mark it as an answer so others can find it :)

Answer (score 2):

The type should reflect what your data contains. So fix the types e.g.

```
let value:ITypeValue & ITypeData & { ChildId: string }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the interface is part of the external library and you don't want to (assuming open source) fork and fix or put in a PR to the maintainers, you can tell the TS server/compiler to expect an error and ignore it.

```
forEach.value(item => ( 
    //@ts-expect-error
    console.log(item.Id + ' - ' + item.Name + ' - ' + item['ChildId']);
));
```

This will also throw an error if the next line does not produce a TS error.